# Solve a recurrence using Akra-Bazzi method where $p$ is not integer and integration is not easy

Tags: recurrence-relation

I recently faced this problem in *CLRS ed.4* and couldn't find out how to attack it and solve it. Here's the recurrence:
$$T(n)=3T(\frac{n}{3})+8T(\frac{n}{4})+\frac{n^2}{\log{n}}$$

Here's what I tried:
$$\frac{3}{3^p}+\frac{8}{4^p}=1$$
For $p=1$, we get $\frac{3}{3}+\frac{8}{4}>1$ and for $p=2$, we get $\frac{3}{3^2}+\frac{8}{4^2}<1$. So we conclude that $1<p<2$. Using numerical methods, we get $p\approx1.85674$. Then we can write:
$$T(n)=\Theta\left(n^p(1+\int_1^n{\frac{x^2}{x^{p+1}\log{x}}}\,\mathrm{d}x)\right)=\Theta\left(n^p+n^p\int_1^n{\frac{1}{x^{p-1}\log{x}}}\,\mathrm{d}x\right)$$

Here's where I'm stuck. I know $1<p<2$ but I can't figure out or guess the intergral answer. I suspect we don't need to calculate the integral actually, but then how can we solve the recurrence then?

Any hint or help is so much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is in $\Theta(\frac{n^{2-p}}{\log n})$ and, substituing it back in the Akra-Bazzi formula, you get $T(n) = \Theta(n^p \cdot \frac{n^{2-p}}{\log n}) = \Theta(\frac{n^2}{\log n})$.

For the lower bound you can use:
$$
\int_{2}^n \frac{1}{x^{p-1} \log x} \text{d}x \ge 
\int_{2}^n \frac{1}{x^{p-1} \log n} \text{d}x = 
\frac{1}{\log n}\int_{2}^n x^{1-p} \text{d}x =
\Omega(\frac{n^{2-p}}{\log n}).
$$

For the upper bound, let $t = \frac{n}{\log^{1/(2-p)} n}$ and notice that $\log t = \log n - o(\log n) = \Theta(\log n)$. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{2}^n \frac{1}{x^{p-1} \log x} \text{d}x &=
\int_{2}^{t} \frac{1}{x^{p-1} \log x} \text{d}x +
\int_{t}^n \frac{1}{x^{p-1} \log x} \text{d}x \\
&\le \int_{2}^{t} x^{1-p} \text{d}x +
\frac{1}{\log t} \int_{t}^n x^{1-p} \text{d}x \\
&= O(t^{2-p}) + O(\frac{n^{2-p}}{\log t}) \\
& =O(\frac{n^{2-p}}{\log n}) + O(\frac{n^{2-p}}{\log n}) = O(\frac{n^{2-p}}{\log n}).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I had never seen something like that. That was perfect! Thanks.